# why my custom fonts via @fontface doesn't work in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this is my theme style, and I provided that in index.js. but currently my fonts doesn't work !.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc91Z.png)

Comment: Have you checked the type of the fonts that you imported to be strong or at least is serializable?if so, what is the result?

Comment: Don't post code as an image, write it into your question with triple backticks (```) to format it as code.